# CSS Image position/focus

Tags: css, image, css-position, background-position

I'm building a website and the image I want to put in the as background I can't put it into the position I want.

I want the 'focus' of the image on the web page to be a few px up to the centre of the image. The width I can see it all, but the height no.

The image resolution is '5760x3840px'.

So, I have this piece of css code for the image's settings.

```
.topwidget{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(../images/welcome_banner_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: bottom 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried background-size: 100%; 100%; with background-position you have given

Comment: Maybe you should edit your image to scale perfectly ?

Comment: have you tried background-size: cover; .. .rather than in percentage ... ?

Comment: try this     background-position: center 10px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this
.topwidget{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url(../images/welcome_banner_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  **background-position: center 10px;**
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, your way didn't quite work, but I change the center px a bit and got it solved!
    .topwidget{
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-image: url(../images/welcome_banner_bg.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: center -425px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 75px 0;
    }